# How to solve when i build docker and getting exit code 100

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, dockerfile

i am using windows OS and build a docker file and getting this error

```
ERROR \[ 2/10\] RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libtesseract3 libtesseract-dev                                                                                                                            6.8s
> -

2/10\] RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libtesseract3 libtesseract-dev:


3.392 Err:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
3.392   404  Not Found


6.166 Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
6.166   404  Not Found
6.670 Err:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
6.670   404  Not Found


6.807 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
6.807 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
6.807 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
6.807 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

> ------

Dockerfile:3
> -

1 |     FROM node:8
2 |
3 | \>\>\> RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libtesseract3 libtesseract-dev
4 |     RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install tesseract-ocr
5 |     RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install tesseract-ocr-hin tesseract-ocr-ara tesseract-ocr-fra tesseract-ocr-fin tesseract-ocr-jpn tesseract-ocr-pol tesseract-ocr-spa tesseract-ocr-rus tesseract-ocr-ita tesseract-ocr-por tesseract-ocr-kor tesseract-ocr-ces tesseract-ocr-dan tesseract-ocr-deu tesseract-ocr-nld tesseract-ocr-swe tesseract-ocr-tur
> -

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libtesseract3 libtesseract-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libleptonica-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install libtesseract3 libtesseract-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install tesseract-ocr-hin tesseract-ocr-ara tesseract-ocr-fra tesseract-ocr-fin tesseract-ocr-jpn tesseract-ocr-pol tesseract-ocr-spa tesseract-ocr-rus tesseract-ocr-ita tesseract-ocr-por tesseract-ocr-kor tesseract-ocr-ces tesseract-ocr-dan tesseract-ocr-deu tesseract-ocr-nld tesseract-ocr-swe tesseract-ocr-tur

RUN apt-get -q -y install git
RUN apt-get -q -y install gcc

COPY app.js .
COPY package.json .
COPY .env .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node app.js
```

I think it's because I use Windows OS so I can't build it or the lib doesnt exist anymore to get
I'm not entirely sure how to go about debugging and solving this problem.

Comment: Node 8 had end of life in 2020 and is no longer supported. Try using a newer version.

Comment: I think that error is saying that Node 8 is so old, that the underlying Debian distribution it's built on has been end-of-lifed too.  Can you use `node:20` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use a more recent Node image. Would also suggest consolidating the various `RUN` commands because you're slowing down the build with repeated `apt-get update`.

```
FROM node:20

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -q -y install \
        git \
        gcc \
        libleptonica-dev \
        libtesseract-dev \
        tesseract-ocr \
        tesseract-ocr-hin \
        tesseract-ocr-ara \
        tesseract-ocr-fra \
        tesseract-ocr-fin \
        tesseract-ocr-jpn \
        tesseract-ocr-pol \
        tesseract-ocr-spa \
        tesseract-ocr-rus \
        tesseract-ocr-ita \
        tesseract-ocr-por \
        tesseract-ocr-kor \
        tesseract-ocr-ces \
        tesseract-ocr-dan \
        tesseract-ocr-deu \
        tesseract-ocr-nld \
        tesseract-ocr-swe \
        tesseract-ocr-tur

COPY app.js .
COPY package.json .
COPY .env .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD node app.js
```